# 'How to use higher order functors properly?' or 'How to have serious fun with funsigs?'

Tags: module, ocaml, sml, smlnj, ml

### Motivation

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to use higher order functors in
SML/NJ to any practical end.

According to the
[SML/NJ docs on the implementation's special features](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/features.html),
it should be possible to specify one functor as an argument to another by use of
the `funsig` keyword. Thus, given a signature

```
signature SIG = sig ... end
```

we should be able to specify a functor that will produce a module satisfying
`SIG`, when applied to a structure satisfying some signature `SIG'`. E.g.,

```
funsig Fn (S:SIG') = SIG
```

With `Fn` declared in this way, we should then (be able to define another
functor that takes *this* functor as an argument. I.e., we can define a module
that is parameterized over another parameterized module, and presumably use the
latter within the former; thus:

```
functor Fn' (functor Fn:SIG) =
struct
...
structure S' = Fn (S:SIG')
...
end
```

It all looks good in theory, but I can't figure out how to actually make use of
this pattern.

### Example Problems

Here are two instances where I've tried to use this pattern, only to find
it impracticable:

#### First attempt

For my first attempt, just playing around, I tried to make a functor that would
take a functor implementing an ordered set, and produce a module for dealing
with sets of integers (not really useful, but it would let you parameterize sets
of a given type over different set implementations). I can define the
following structures, and they will compile (using *Standard ML of New Jersey
v110.7*):

```
structure IntOrdKey : ORD_KEY
= struct
    type ord_key = int
    val compare = Int.compare
end

funsig SET_FN (KEY:ORD_KEY) = ORD_SET

functor IntSetFn (functor SetFn:SET_FN) =
struct
    structure Set = SetFn (IntOrdKey)
end
```

But when I actually try to apply `IntSetFn` to a functor that should satisfy the
`SET_FN` funsig, it just doesn't parse:

```
- structure IntSet = IntSetFn (functor ListSetFn);
= ;
= ;;
stdIn:18.1-24.2 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN SEMICOLON SEMICOLON
- structure IntSet = IntSetFn (functor BinarySetFn) ;
= ;
= ;
stdIn:19.1-26.2 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN SEMICOLON SEMICOLON
```

#### Second attempt

My second attempt fails in two ways.

I have defined a structure of nested modules implementing polymorphic and
monomorphic stacks ([the source file](https://github.com/aBathologist/sml-utils/blob/master/collect.sml), for the curious). To
implement a monomorphic stack, you do

```
- structure IntStack = Collect.Stack.Mono (type elem = int);
structure IntStack : MONO_STACK?
- IntStack.push(1, IntStack.empty);
val it = - : IntStack.t
```

and so forth. It seems to work fine so far. Now, I want to define a module that
parameterizes over this functor. So I have defined a funsig for the
`Collect.Stack.Mono` functor (which can be seen in my repo). Then, following the
pattern indicated above, I tried to define the following test module:

```
(* load my little utility library *)
CM.autoload("../../../utils/sources.cm");

functor T (functor StackFn:MONO_STACK) =
struct
    structure S = StackFn (type elem = int)
    val x = S.push (1, S.empty)
end
```

But this won't compile! I get a type error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: S.elem * S.t
  operand:         [int ty] * S.t
  in expression:
    S.push (1,S.empty)

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:292.17-292.20
```

Yet, inside functor `T`, I appear to be using the exact same instantiation
pattern that works perfectly at the top level. What am I missing?

Unfortunately, that's not the end of my mishaps. Now, I remove the line
causing the type error, leaving,

```
functor T (functor StackFn:MONO_STACK) =
struct
    structure S = StackFn (type elem = int)
end
```

This compiles fine:

```
[scanning ../../../utils/sources.cm]
val it = true : bool
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
functor T(<param>: sig functor StackFn : <fctsig> end) :
         sig
           structure S : <sig>
         end
val it = () : unit
```

But I cannot actually instantiate the module! Apparently the path access syntax
is unsupported for higher order functors?

```
- structure Test = T (functor Collect.Stack.Mono);
stdIn:43.36-43.43 Error: syntax error: deleting  DOT ID DOT
```

I am at a lost.

### Questions

I have three related questions:

1. Is there a basic principle of higher-order functors in SML/NJ that I'm
   missing, or is it just an incompletely, awkwardly implemented feature of the
   language?
2. If the latter, where can I turn for more elegant and practicable higher order
   functors? (Hopefully an SML, but I'll dip into OCaml if necessary.)
3. Is there perhaps a different approach I should taking to achieve these kinds
   of effects that avoids higher order functors all together?

Many thanks in advance for any answers, hints, or followup questions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding your first attempt, the right syntax to apply your `IntSetFn` functor is:

```
structure IntSet = IntSetFn (functor SetFn = ListSetFn)
```

The same applies to your application of the `Test` functor in the second attempt:

```
structure Test = T (functor StackFn = Collect.Stack.Mono)
```

That should fix the syntax errors.

The type error you get when trying to use your stack structure `S` inside functor `T` has to do with the way you defined the `MONO_STACK` funsig:

```
funsig MONO_STACK (E:ELEM) = MONO_STACK
```

This just says that it returns *a* `MONO_STACK` structure, with a fully abstract `elem` type. It does not say that its `elem` type is gonna be the same as `E.elem`. According to that, I would able to pass in a functor like

```
functor F (E : ELEM) = struct type elem = unit ... end
```

to your functor `T`. Hence, inside `T`, the type system is not allowed to assume that type `S.elem` = `int`, and consequently you get a type error.

To fix this, you need to refine the `MONO_STACK` funsig as follows:

```
funsig MONO_STACK (E:ELEM) = MONO_STACK where type elem = E.elem
```

That should eliminate the type error.

[Edit]

As for your questions:

1. Higher-order functors are a little awkward syntactically in SML/NJ because it tries to stay 100% compatible with plain SML, which separates the namespace of functors from that for structures. If that wasn't the case then there wouldn't be the need for funsigs as a separate namespace either (and other syntactic baroqueness), and the language of signatures could simply be extended to include functor types.
2. Moscow ML is another SML dialect with a higher-order module extension that resolves the compatibility issue somewhat more elegantly (and is more expressive). There also was (now mostly dead) ALice ML, yet another SML dialect with higher-order functors that simply dropped the awkward namespace separation. OCaml of course did not have this constraint in the first place, so its higher-order modules are also more regular syntactically.
3. The approach seems fine.